# Вложенные анонимные типы?

Tags: c#

Всем привет, имеется вот такой пример:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Анонимные типы в анонимных типах.

        var instance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27, Id = new { Number = 123 } };

        Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Age = {1}, Id = {2}", instance.Name, instance.Age, instance.Id.Number);


        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Как видно, в данном примере - один анонимный тип вкладывается в другой. Я понял, что это можно изобразить примерно так: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также как я понял, когда я создаю анонимный тип, Visual Studio создает новый класс и новый класс создается когда компилятор встречает новый анонимный тип. Новизна определяется путем сравнения имен свойств, их порядка и типов.
И получается, что когда я создаю новый анонимный тип, то Visual Studio порождает (примерно) следующий класс:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ x = {x}, y = {y} }", Type = "<Anonymous Type>")]
public sealed class Anonymous<TX, TY>
{
    private readonly TX field_x;
    private readonly TY field_y;

    public TX x { get { return field_x; } }
    public TY y { get { return field_y; } }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public Anonymous(PX x, PY y)
    {
        field_x = x;
        field_y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object value) { /* тут имплементация */ }
    public override int GetHashCode() { /* тут имплементация */ }
    public override string ToString() { /* тут имплементация */ }
}
```

Но если у меня один анонимный тип вложен в другой, то эти порожденные классы будут Nested классами ли нет?

Comment: Где вы здесь увидели, что один анонимный тип вкладывается в другой?!

Comment: а почему они должны быть вложенными?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, судя по картинке, первоначально код был таким: `var instance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27, Id = new { Number=123 } };`

Comment: прошу прощения за ошибку - не тот пример кода скопировал, ДАЖЕ НЕ ПОСМОТРЕЛ...мой косяк. внес правку.

Comment: @BadCats всегда можно взять любой декомпилятор (или хотя бы ildasm, который идет вместе со студией) и посмотреть. Но я ставлю на "нет"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Практика — критерий истины! Попробуем и посмотрим, что получилось.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27, Id = new { Number = 123 } };
        var allTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
        foreach (var t in allTypes)
        {
            var nestedTypes = t.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {t.FullName}, nested types: {nestedTypes.Length}");
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
Name: <>f__AnonymousType0`3, nested types: 0
Name: <>f__AnonymousType1`1, nested types: 0
Name: NestedAnonymous.Program, nested types: 0
```

Таким образом, для компилятора второй анонимный тип ничем не отличается от первого, вложенных типов в программе нету. Этого и стоило ожидать: ведь когда мы пишем `var instance = new { List = new List<int>() };`, мы же не ожидаем, что `List<int>` окажется вложенным типом анонимного типа?

---

Для сравнения, положим ещё один вложенный тип:

```
class Program
{
    class Nested { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27, Id = new { Number = 123 } };
        var allTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
        foreach (var t in allTypes)
        {
            var nestedTypes = t.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {t.FullName}, nested types: {nestedTypes.Length}");
        }
    }
}
```

Получаем такой вывод:

```
Name: <>f__AnonymousType0`3, nested types: 0
Name: <>f__AnonymousType1`1, nested types: 0
Name: NestedAnonymous.Program, nested types: 1
Name: NestedAnonymous.Program+Nested, nested types: 0
```

Мы видим, что у `Program` появился вложенный тип, и что имя вложенного типа содержит имя объемлющего типа, отделённое плюсиком. (Это, разумеется, внутренняя подробность имплементации анонимных типов компилятором в поставке MSVC 2015, другие компиляторы могут делать это по-другому.)